# MYOBAdvanced Web API LogOut - You have been logged out due to exceeding the number of users in the system

Tags: acumatica, logout, webapi

Our system logs In successfully in to MYOBAdvanced, do the stuff it needs to do (Create Sales orders, Quotes, etc) and then attempt to log Out.

However after the system is running for sometime, we start receiving the error on MYOBAdvanced UI:

> 'You have been logged out due to exceeding the number of users in the system.'

The  `screen.Logout()` indicates that the logout process is successful still receiving the error on MYOBAdvanced UI.

Has this been already fixed in Acumatica 5.2.1567.33 or MYOBAdvanced(2015.3.2.1193) ?

Below is the code for reference:

```
public class Advanced {
static Screen oScreen = new Screen();

        public static Boolean fConnect(string sCompany, ref string sError) {
            try { 
                oScreen.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
                oScreen.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                oScreen.EnableDecompression = true;
                oScreen.Timeout = 200000;  // Timeout set to 2 min
                oScreen.Url = sCompany;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                sError = "ERR~~fConnect " + ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static string fLogin(string sCompany, string sUser, string sPwd) {
            try {
                String sError = "";
                Boolean bConnect = fConnect(sCompany, ref sError);
       
                if (!bConnect){
                    return "ERR~Unable To Connect To Company File <" + sCompany + "> " + sError;
                }

                LoginResult oLogin = new LoginResult();
                oLogin = oScreen.Login(sUser, sPwd);  
                
                oScreen.SetLocaleName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

                if (oLogin.Code == 0){
                    String sDBVersion = "";
                    if (fCheckDBVersion(ref sDBVersion, ref sError))
                    {
                        return "OK ~~";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return "ERR~~fLogin " + sError; 
                    };
                }
                else {
                    return oLogin.Message;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return "ERR~~fLogin " + ex.Message; 
            }
        }
        public static String fLogOut()
        {
            try
            {
                oScreen.Logout();
                return "OK ~~";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return "ERR~~fLogOut " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There were problems in earlier versions of Acumatica with the Logout function and this was fixed starting 5.20.1525. However due to a different licensing model in MYOB Advanced a similar issue existed there too and was acknowledged by their team. According to them this was supposed to be addressed in the update released last week. Do you have a new version on your site and can you let us know if the problem still happens?

Comment: Hi Gabriel,The issue still persist on MYOB Advanced version Version 2015.3.3.226 (5.20.1686.18)

Comment: @JoseJoya are you seeing the LogOut function in the API or is it missing? Are all your login calls paired with logouts?

Comment: yes, we are using the oScreen.Logout() function and I log out after calling each function. It means, I login, then get whatever I need to retrieve (Sales Orders, Customers, Items, etc), then logOut.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your implementation but in most of cases using web services people create new cookies and it will assign new session.
From my standpoint you have to use only one Login method and save your cookie somewhere to use it in next calls.

Comment: We use only one login method and we also store the cookie container as described in code above..